# Can $P(X>Y)>1/2$, $P(Y>Z)>1/2$, and $P(Z>X)>1/2$ at the same time?

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be random variables. Is it possible that $P(X>Y)>1/2$, $P(Y>Z)>1/2$, and $P(Z>X)>1/2$ at the same time? My intuition says that this is not possible. I tried to prove it using Inclusion-Exclusion principle but I still couldn't figure this out.

Here's my attempt:
Denote by the events $A=\{X>Y\}$, $B=\{Y>Z\}$, and $C=\{Z>X\}$.
Assume that $P(A),P(B),P(C)>1/2$.
Then we have
$$\frac{3}{2}<P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=P(A\cup B\cup C) +P(A\cap B) + P(B\cap C)+P(C\cap A).$$
Note that $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(X>Y>Z>X) = 0$.
I was trying to show that the right-hand side is less than or equal to $3/2$ but the only clue I have is $P(A\cap B)\leq P(X\leq Z) = 1-P(X>Z)<1/2$ and, similarly, $P(B\cap C), P(C\cap A)<1/2$, and I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counter example, consider if there are three equiprobable cases i, ii, iii:

$$\begin{array}{l|lllll}
\text{Case i:}& Z=0; & Y=1; & X=2\\
\text{Case ii:}& & Y=1; & X=2; & Z=3\\
\text{Case iii:}& & & X=2; & Z=3; & Y=4\\
\end{array}$$

Then $P(X>Y) = P(Y>Z) = P(Z>X) = \frac 23$.

Comment: How silly of me to insist that my guess was correct. I just found out from your answer that $\frac{2}{3}$ is, in fact, the maximum of all possible value of $\min\{P(X>Y),P(Y>Z),P(Z>X)\}$, since $P(X>Y)+P(Y>Z)+P(Z>X)\leq 1+P(X>Y>Z)+P(Y>Z>X)+P(Z>X>Y)\leq 4- (P(X>Y)+P(Y>Z)+P(Z>X))$.